# white-space and minimum length validation in custom search

Tags: 7, ajax, search, forms

I'm using custom search for my website. Now I wan't to validate user input before search like validate white-spaces (just enter space in search box and you'll find all things goes wrong).

For minimum length validation drupal take cares for minimum 3 character, but if you enter less then 3 characters and press search button search results page appears and then it shows an error that you need to enter keyword with 3 characters or more.

I don't want to go on search results page until all validation criteria passes. In this case I want just red border on search box (this is happen when no text inserted in the search box and you press search button).

How can I validate white-space, minimum search keyword length and restrict user on same page until all validation criteria passes in custom search module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.. :) You need to modify `custom search` js file for achieve this. This file can be found at `sites\all\modules\custom_search\js\custom_search.js`. Edit this file as following..

```
if (!Drupal.settings.custom_search.solr) {
        // Check if the search box is not empty on submit
        $('form.search-form', context).submit(function(){
          var box = $(this).find('input.custom-search-box');

       //Search Box Patch Start

      var searchBox=$.trim(box.val());
          var searchLen = searchBox.length;     

          if(searchLen < 3)
          {
            searchBox = "";
          }
          if (searchBox != undefined && (searchBox == '' || searchBox == $(this).find('input.default-text').val())) {
            $(this).find('input.custom-search-box').addClass('error');
            return false;
          }

          //Search Box Patch End
```

Here I edited this file for minimum 3 characters to search (without white-space) and if this criteria fails then no redirecting on search results page, you'll find red border on search box on the same page. This is my requirement, but you can edit file this as per your desire output.

(NOTE: Make sure that you disable [Block Lazyloader](http://drupal.org/project/blocklazyloader) module for use `custom_search.js` otherwise it will not work).

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) and extend your validation process by adding $form['#validate'][] = 'custom_validation()'